# API hooking and server network

Tags: c++, masm32

I've app which sends requests to server through the function send().It was written in C++ with WinSock.
I need to change IP address server.It's something like hooking API send() and write my API.

It sends packets to 73.455...

I'd like to change to 64.456...

How can i do it please?

I am newbie in this case.Anyone could help me with code in MASM32 or C++?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't you can chance the source code ?

Comment: 455 and 456 are invalid values for IP addresses.

Comment: +1 for masm, but vtc because you're either asking us to teach you X or write the whole thing for you, and that's not in-scope.  Try to write it, if you have trouble we can help with specific problems.

Comment: Ok.Thanks.I tried to write some code.If i have problem then i'll write here.

Comment: Nourney,I can't change ip in the debugger.